# Advanced arrows in latex

Tags: pdftex

Is there any package in latex consisting of commands for the following arrow?
[image]

Comment: There are many ways to create such an arrow. You will get better responses if you can describe the context in which it will be used. Is this meant to be a symbol on a single line? An arrow pointing from text above to text on a line below? You should also create a ["Minimal Working Example"](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}`, even if it does not produce your desired output. Then describe where the arrow belongs.

Comment: I remember you to see also the list of the symbols.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mathb` set in `mathabx` has a `dlsh` command. Here is how to borrow it without changing your maths fonts:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathb}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathb}{m}{n}{%
 <-6> mathb5
<6-7> mathb6
<7-8> mathb7
<8-9> mathb8
<9-10> mathb9
 <10-12> mathb10
  <12-> mathb12
  } {}%
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathb}{U}{mathb}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\dlsh}{\mathrel}{mathb}{"EA}

\begin{document}

\[ X \dlsh Y\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That is absolutely good. Thank you so much for your instruction!